# DataFrame to range of values of multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:- https://github.com/dsuborno/dsuborno/blob/main/README.md

and from this dataset I want to sort out datas from columns for maxHR>221 age> 40 and Heart Disease = 1, how can I perform this action using pyhon?

Comment: What have you tried and what's the problem?

Comment: Your data can't be accessed. Please include a sample so that we could understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry for before, its my first time using github. But now i think it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`df.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or boolean indexing

```py
df_ = df.query('MaxHR > 221 and Age > 40 and HeartDisease == 1')

# Or

df_ = df[df['MaxHR'].gt(221) & df['Age'].gt(40) & df['HeartDisease'].eq(1)]
```

Comment: umm its not working, i am using it like this:import pandas
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pandas.read_csv("heart.csv")

df_ = df[df['MaxHR'].gt(221) & df['Age'].gt(40) & df['HeartDisease'].eq(1)]
print(df_.to_string) and it is showing me this:PS E:\Projectfile> & C:/Users/i3/anaconda3/python.exe e:/Projectfile/readfile.py
<bound method DataFrame.to_string of Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Age, Sex, ChestPainType, RestingBP, Cholesterol, FastingBS, RestingECG, MaxHR, ExerciseAngina, Oldpeak, ST_Slope, HeartDisease]
Index: []>

Comment: @subornodas Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: I cannot figure it  out

Comment: @subornodas Empty dataframe means there is no rows satisfy the condition.

Comment: yes i guessed that too ngl, theres no MaxHR greater than 221. My bad

Comment: Now it is working excellent with the second and what platform should i use for py while i am working with dataframe?

Comment: @subornodas I don't quite get the meaning of platform here. Do you mean operating system or something else?